# Updating all the record for a column in a table with value from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I want to update all the values of RequestId column of IIL_CHANGE_REQUEST Table with the RequestId of TABLE_NAME_4MINS Table where REQUESTBY column in both tables are same. I am trying to do this in oracle daatabalse(sql developer)

My query:

```
Update IIL_CHANGE_REQUEST 
set REQUESTID=(SELECT TABLE_NAME_4MINS.REQUESTID
                     FROM TABLE_NAME_4MINS
                     WHERE IIL_CHANGE_REQUEST.REQUESTBY = TABLE_NAME_4MINS.REQUESTBY) 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME_4MINS.REQUESTID
                     FROM TABLE_NAME_4MINS
                     WHERE IIL_CHANGE_REQUEST.REQUESTBY = TABLE_NAME_4MINS.REQUESTBY)
```

But every time I do this I get an error saying:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
Update IIL_CHANGE_REQUEST 
set REQUESTID=(SELECT TABLE_NAME_4MINS.REQUESTID
                     FROM TABLE_NAME_4MINS
                     WHERE IIL_CHANGE_REQUEST.REQUESTBY = TABLE_NAME_4MINS.REQUESTBY) 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME_4MINS.REQUESTID
                     FROM TABLE_NAME_4MINS
                     WHERE IIL_CHANGE_REQUEST.REQUESTBY = TABLE_NAME_4MINS.REQUESTBY)
```

Error report -

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Please anyone help how can I do it.

Comment: *single-row subquery returns more than one row* - what is unclear in this words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do in such cases. If you don't really care, take *any* value, for example minimum:

```
update iil_change_request a
set a.requestid = (select min(b.requestid)            --> here
                   from table_name_4mins b
                   where a.requestby = b.requestby) 
where exists (select c.requestid
              from table_name_4mins c
              where a.requestby = c.requestby);
```

If that's not what you want, then you'll have to figure out what to do with those "duplicates". Perhaps you'll have to include yet another `WHERE` condition, or fix data, or ... who knows? I don't, while you should.

Comment: Thank you so much  I didn't relize that there may be multiple cases for which REQUESTBY is same that is why I am getting error. Now I get what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a condition to narrow down returned rows to the only per `REQESTSTBY`, for example you can replace `...` with a column name in the query below to return just first row as per `order-by`:

```sql
MERGE INTO IIL_CHANGE_REQUEST r
USING (
        SELECT *
        FROM (
           SELECT REQUESTBY, REQUESTID
                ,row_number()over(partition by REQUESTBY order by ...) rn
           FROM TABLE_NAME_4MINS
        ) 
        where rn=1
        ) t
ON (r.REQUESTBY = t.REQUESTBY)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
   set REQUESTID=t.REQUESTID;
```

Comment: Thank you so much I didn't relize that there may be multiple cases for which REQUESTBY is same that is whya I am getting error.